# Is this a flake8 false positive, or am I really doing something wrong?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension, flake8, pyflakes

I have a function that can be simplified to this code sample:

```
def test_fun():
    for i in range(17):
        item = i
        print(item)
    for i in range(42):
        items = [[i], [i], [i]]
        flatten_items = [item[0] for item in items]
        print(flatten_items)
```

When I run pyflakes (1.3.0) or flake8 (3.2.0), I get the following report:

```
/tmp/test.py:7:38: F812 list comprehension redefines 'item' from line 3
```

What I see is that the `item` variable is indeed used twice, but under different scopes, so it shouldn't be reported, right?

Also, even if there was no second loop, why shouldn't I be allowed to rewrite the `item` variable, as I've finished working with the one I defined on line 3 since the `print`?

So, is this a false positive, or I am really writting a very poor piece of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehension in Python 2.7 leaks local variable to enclosing scope.

```
>>> import sys; sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=12, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> [item for item in ['a', 'b', 'c']]
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> item
'c'
```

This behavior was fixed in Python 3:

```
>>> import sys; sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> [item for item in ['a', 'b', 'c']]
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> item
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'item' is not defined
```

Comment: So this is exactly the same as doing a `for item in items: flatten_items.append(item[0])`, but in this case I don't get any error or warning from pyflakes. Why?

Comment: maybe they simply does not have a checker for it? I'm not familiar with flakes tool